grep command fails with out-of-memory error
I encountered an OOM issue (this happens every-time I execute it) on running
grep -Fxvf file1 file2

file1 size: ~200MB
file2 size: ~300MB
number of records in each file: ~300K
avg records length: ~1K (only ASCII characters)
diff between two files is ~18K records
Available free memory: ~16GB
I tried with several different grep versions and in VM, WSL and also on a physical server, but got the same result.
Note that I ran the same command with only having few lines from both files to identify it doesn’t run into an infinite loop due to having some special character in the files and it was successful.
Is this normal?
I’m trying to output records from file2 which do not exist in file1.
I already resolved my requirement by awk in the same environment and got the output in less than about 10 seconds, but I’m wondering why the grep results in OOM.
I used the same command almost always when I needed to do querying same requirements and even I had compared two very big files like two files with ~2GB of size and each one ~90M records and records containing maximum ~20 ASCII characters without any issue in the same boxes.
I used GNU grep 2.7, 2.16 on SLES12, and GNU grep 3.7 on Ubnutu 22.04 in WSL.

What are you trying to do here? You're reading a line of file1 as a fixed string and then printing every line in file2 which doesn't contain the string you just read in... for each line of file1, so about ~300K times. This could very easily lead to a giant output. Is this really what you mean to do?

Does the file1 file contain strings that need to match the full length of the lines in the other file, or could they match anywhere on the lines of the other file? There are other tools available for doing efficient comparisons of large files, such as comm and join. You are currently essentially checking 200 MB of strings against each single line of a 300 MB file, in the worst case.

When you use the -f file option, all of those values are read into the working memory of grep. This is almost certainly what is causing the OOM condition. You can break up the file into smaller sub-sections OR you can recompile grep with a larger buffer for the -f option. It may be with newer greps that there is a cmd-line option to increase buffer size. You could also rewrite this in awk, (very simple one-liner) but it would be slower than compiled c code.

What operating system and what grep are you using? Is this GNU grep on Linux?

As @kos mentioned, comm is the tool for doing what you're trying to do but you'll need to sort each input file first, comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2).

Even if/when grep reads the whole of file1 into memory, they sat it's only about ~200MB. So it does seem a bit surprising it'd run out of memory due to that. Even with 10x overhead, it'd still be only 2 GB, much less than the 16 GB they say is free. So I do wonder what it actually does.

@EdMorton Thanks for addressing the sort thing, I'm a bit reckless when typing comments.

thank you all for your valuable advices.

Free memory is irrelevant. It's running out of virtual memory, not RAM. RAM availability only impacts performance, applications always use virtual mem.

@ilkkachu You're indeed right about printing, I suppose it would just process that many lines (I removed my previous comment since there's nothing useful left in it because of the wrong command and the wrong statement)

@Barmar, you still need to have enough RAM+swap to have some place to put the data, right? And if the amount of "free memory" mentioned includes any swap (whatever little one is likely to have nowadays)... The whole virtual address space on a 64-bit system is more like infinite compared to even the ~100 times the pattern file size Stéphane's answer points at.

Your process might have more RAM than virtual memory, or vice versa, depending on kernel's overcommit settings, cgroups limits and ulimit -v.

If you look at the code of the GNU implementation of grep for what happens when invoked as grep -Fxvf file1 file2, you'll see it:

reads the whole contents of file1 in memory
deduplicates the lines in that list using a hash table (for which it needs a few extra bytes of memory per line though that memory is reclaimed after deduplication)¹.
then it compiles a pattern tree using the Aho–Corasick algorithm (same Aho as the a in awk, and same algorithm as was used in the original fgrep in the 70s), so as to minimise the number of comparisons when it comes to looking for matching lines in the subject.

3 happens even when -F is combined with -x for which, for more than a few strings to match, it would likely be much more efficient to use a hash table (and ironically, one was just built in stage 2).
It's likely that last part 3 that is most CPU-intensive and requires most memory.
Running:
base64 -w 1000 /dev/urandom | head -n 10000 |
  \time -f %MKiB grep -Fvxf - /dev/null

And varying the 10000, I see it allocating around 96 bytes of RAM for each byte of the pattern file, so that would be 18GiB for your 200MiB file.
Watching it in gdb, we see it allocating a struct trie (64 bytes) for most if not all bytes in the pattern file at least.
grep is typically used to search for a string or regexp or a short list of strings or regexps on arbitrary sized input, it's  not designed to compare files.
For that, using a hash table as you'd do in awk or perl with:
awk '!file1_processed {hash[$0]; next}
     ! ($0 in hash)' file1 file1_processed=1 file2

Is the way to go. That only needs to store the whole contents of file1 in memory (plus the hash table overhead). And the matching in file2 is just a hash table lookup.
For already sorted files, using comm would be even more efficient.

Now looking at other grep implementations one can find or build on GNU/Linux:
$ base64 -w 1000 /dev/urandom | head -n 20000 > random
$ \time -f '%MKiB %E' grep -Fvxf random random
Command exited with non-zero status 1
1918504KiB 0:04.01

$ \time -f '%MKiB %E' busybox grep -Fvxf random random
Command exited with non-zero status 1
24644KiB 0:15.55

$ \time -f '%MKiB %E' toybox grep -Fvxf random random
Command exited with non-zero status 1
22892KiB 0:00.11

$ \time -f '%MKiB %E' ast-open-grep -Fvxf random random
Command exited with non-zero status 1
48416KiB 0:21.90

$ \time -f '%MKiB %E' heirloom/grep/grep_su3 -Fvxf random random
Command exited with non-zero status 1
805476KiB 0:13.58

GNU and heirloom toolchest (from OpenSolaris likely based on original fgrep) use a lot of memory but are "relatively" fast. busybox and ast-open use less memory but are much slower possibly using a dumber algorithm.
Toybox' is very fast (though still significantly slower than the awk approach) without using much memory (just over the size of file1). It uses a sort of crude hash table in that the "hash" is the first byte of the string, so though it does simple comparisons, it only needs to compare with the list of strings for which the first byte is the same, which in the case of base64 encoded random strings like in my tests means the number of comparisons to perform is divided by 64.
If instead of 20000 1000-byte long lines of random base64 text, we use the output of seq -f %01000g 20000 where only the last bytes of the lines change, the timings become quite different, with GNU/heirloom being the fastest by far (under a second, showing the benefit of using the Aho–Corasick algorithm), busybox/ast-open/toybox seemingly taking forever (I gave up waiting after 5 minutes), toybox' falling behind ast-open's (not busybox which becomes the slowest by far²) as the first byte is always the same, and also because all comparisons need to compare the first 990+ bytes, so we can expect it to be about 64*990 as slow as for base64-encoded random data.

¹ It also records in another table where the patterns were read from though it's only used when reporting regexp errors, so rather pointless for fixed strings.
² Maybe because it uses strstr() to search a string within a string instead of strcmp() even with -x.
